# How to prevent rows with duplicated indices / keys to be appended to a data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, uniqueidentifier, unique-key

I have data in which the combination of two variables ("ManufactererId" and "ProductId") constitute unique keys / identifiers. The data looks like this:

```
my.data <- data.frame(ManufactererId = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
                      ProductId = c(1, 2, 1, 7),
                      Price = c(12.99, 149.00, 0.99, 3.99))
my.data
#   ManufactererId ProductId  Price
# 1              1         1  12.99
# 2              1         2 149.00
# 3              2         1   0.99
# 4              2         7   3.99
```

I want to ensure that I cannot accidentally add another row with a pair of ManufactererId - ProductId equal to what is already present in the table (like the unique constraint on a database table).

That is, if I try to add a row with ManufactererId = 2 and ProductId = 7 to my data frame:

```
my.data <- rbind(my.data, data.frame(ManufactererId = 2, ProductId = 7, Price = 120.00))
```

...it should fail with an error. How can this be achieved?

Or should I use a different data type?

Answer (score 7):

**1) zoo** Whether this is convenient or not depends on what operations you want to do but zoo objects have unique indexes.  We can construct a text index by pasting together the two Id columns.

```
library(zoo)
z <- with(my.data, zoo(Price, paste(ManufactererId, ProductId)))

z <- c(z, zoo(90, "1 1")) # Error, not appended
z <- c(z, zoo(90, "1 3")) # OK
```

Note that the data part of a zoo object can be a vector as shown above or a matrix in case you have more than just Price in the data.

**2) SQLite**  This could be done with any of a number of databases but we will use SQLite here.  First we create a table with a unique index in an SQLite database and then we insert rows.

```
library(RSQLite)

con <- dbConnect(SQLite())
dbWriteTable(con, "my", my.data, row.names = FALSE)
dbGetQuery(con, "create unique index ix on my(ManufactererId, ProductId)")

dbGetQuery(con, sprintf("insert into my values(%d, %d, %d)", 1, 1, 99)) # error
dbGetQuery(con, sprintf("insert into my values(%d, %d, %d)", 1, 13, 90)) # OK
```

Comment: Added second approach.

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like this: Where `keys` is your unique-key

```
append_save <- function(DF, to_be_appended, keys=c("ManufactererId", "ProductId")){
  if(ncol(DF) != ncol(to_be_appended) || !all(names(DF) %in% names(to_be_appended))){
    stop("must have the same columns")
  }
  if(nrow(merge(DF, to_be_appended, by=keys))==0){
    rbind(DF, to_be_appended)
  } else {
    stop("Trying to append douplicated indices")
  }
}
```

Test it:

```
to_be_appended = data.frame(ManufactererId=2,ProductId=17,Price=3.99)
append_save(my.data, to_be_appended) # works
to_be_appended_err = data.frame(ManufactererId=2,ProductId=7,Price=3.99)
append_save(my.data, to_be_appended_err) # error
```

If you append data only based on key-columns you could use `data.table` as follows:

```
append_save <- function(DF, to_be_appended, keys=c("ManufactererId", "ProductId")){
  if(!all(keys %in% names(to_be_appended))){
    stop("key-columns must be present")
  }
  if(nrow(data.table::merge(DF, to_be_appended, on=keys))==0){
    data.table::setDF(data.table::rbindlist(list(DF, to_be_appended), fill = TRUE))[]
  } else {
    stop("Trying to append douplicated indices")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this in base R is to use an `environment` as a dictionary or hash-map like object.
    my.dict <- new.env()

First, write some helper functions

```
make_key <- function(ManufactererId, ProductId)
  paste(ManufactererId, ProductId)

set_value <- function(key, value, dict){
         ## checking here assures desired behavior 
         if(any(key %in% names(dict)))
            stop("This key has been used")
         assign(key, value,  envir=dict)
}
```

then, you can generate keys like

```
keys <- make_key(my.data[[1]], my.data[[2]])
```

to set values, you need to be a bit more careful

```
# don't just do this as the first element is used by assign
# set_value(keys, my.data[[3]], dict=my.dict)

mapply(set_value, keys, my.data[[3]], MoreArgs = list(dict=my.dict))
ls.str(my.dict) # better than str for environments
# 1 1 :  num 13
# 1 2 :  num 149
# 2 1 :  num 0.99
# 2 7 :  num 3.99

set_value("1 1", 4, my.dict)
# Error in set_value("1 1", 4, my.dict) : This key has been used
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to rbind new data excluding duplicates:

```
library(data.table)
my.data = data.table(ManufactererId = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
                     ProductId = c(1, 2, 1, 7),
                     Price = c(12.99, 149.00, 0.99, 3.99),
                     key = c("ManufactererId","ProductId"))
x = my.data # my data will be called 'x'
y = data.table(ManufactererId = 2, ProductId = 7, Price = 120.00)
rbind(x, y[!x, on=key(x)])
#   ManufactererId ProductId  Price
#1:              1         1  12.99
#2:              1         2 149.00
#3:              2         1   0.99
#4:              2         7   3.99
```

Although you don't need to set a key but just provide character vector to `on` argument directly. I think it's worth to use key which simply reflects our business expectations in regards to data structure.

---

If you want to raise an error on such case you can use the following:

```
unique.rbind = function(x, y, by=key(x)) {
    if (nrow(x[y, nomatch=0L, on=by])) stop("duplicates in 'y'")
    rbind(x, y)
}
unique.rbind(x, y)
# Error in unique.rbind(x, y) : duplicates in 'y'
```

None of `y` rows gets inserted in case of error.